# Perceptron in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn library. I have a question about the attribute: `n_iter_`. When executing the code I get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_iter_'`. Also try using `n_iter` but I get the same error, or maybe I am misspelling the attribute. It is not all the code, if you need more information, let me know

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


ppn= Perceptron(n_iter_=40, eta0= 0.1, random_state=1)
ppn.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
```

Comment: It should be `ppn= Perceptron(n_iter=40, eta0= 0.1, random_state=1)`. Please check the user guide: https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html

Comment: I already tried it and it gives me the same error

Comment: But it works for me...

Comment: Scikit-versions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Perceptron` Model in `sklearn.linear_model` doesn't have `n_iter_` as a parameter. It has following parameters with similar names.

```
max_iter: int, default=1000
The maximum number of passes over the training data (aka epochs). It only impacts the behavior in the fit method, and not the partial_fit method.
```

and

```
n_iter_no_change : int, default=5
Number of iterations with no improvement to wait before early stopping.

New in version 0.20.
```

By looking at your code it looks like you intended to use `max_iter`.

So do

```
ppn=Perceptron(max_iter=40, eta0= 0.1, random_state=1)
ppn.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
```

Note:
You should first `upgrade` your `sklearn` using

```
pip install sklearn -upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

> The attribute given in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html) is `n_iter` and not `n_iter_`

So this should work:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


ppn=Perceptron(n_iter=40, eta0= 0.1, random_state=1)
ppn.fit(X_train_std, y_train)
```

Comment: Issue is with versions ;)

Answer (score 0):

First check which Scikit-learn version you have installed. You can do that by executing

```sh
python -c "import sklearn;print(sklearn.__version__)"
```

on your terminal/environment to which you have the python that executes your code.

Perceptron initial parameters have changed from `n_iter` to `max_iter` in version 0.20. The best way to keep up, head to the documentation or source code of the correct version and read the params: e.g.

documentation: [perceptron docs v.0.23](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html)
source code: [perceptions.0.23 code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e/sklearn/linear_model/_perceptron.py#L8)